# On a particular matrix homomorphism

Tags: matrices

I recently noticed that, for $2\times 2$ matrices, dividing one off-diagonal element by a constant while multiplying the other off-diagonal element by the same constant produces a matrix homomorphism.

i.e., if we call this operation $g$, then it's defined as

$$g\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\right) =\begin{bmatrix}a & (b\cdot\lambda)\\(c/\lambda) & d\end{bmatrix} $$

and then the homomorphism properties are:

$$ g(A) g(B) = g(AB) $$
(where juxtaposition indicates the usual matrix multiplication)
and
$$ g(A)+g(B) = g(A + B).$$

My question(s): Does this homomorphism have a name, any useful applications, and does it hint at any kind of deeper structure?  Are there others like it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your homomorphism is an example of a similarity transform. A similarity transform is a transformation on matrices of the form $X\mapsto AXA^{-1}$ where $A$ is invertible. In your case $A = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda^{1/2} & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{-1/2}\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 4):

You have
$$
g \left( 
\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}
 \right)
=
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda^{-1} & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In fact, all automorphism of a matrix algebra over a field are inner (that is, of the form $x \mapsto t x t^{-1}$), see [Skolem-Noether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem). See also [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379580902219) for a more general situation.